# German Student visa

Tags: germany, visa

How difficult is it to get a German Visa for a second Master degree in the same field but with advanced courses as a prerequisite for Ph.D.?

Comment: I joined my first degree very late after 1 and a half month from when the course started and my institute had a continuous assessment system. I was left so far behind when I enrolled and I had backlogs because of this. But I made it up for that in my second year with my research project, thesis, and paper

Comment: I don't understand why you want to study a second masters degree in the same field even after reading your comment above. Please note that if I have this question, then the officer who issues the visa could have the same question i.e. why do you want to study the masters degree in the same field again..

Comment: My first choice was actually PhD. I approached some of the reputed Professors in United States and Germany who lead funded research in my area of interest. The response I got from them was that my research so far is just a small step into the area and that I need more expertise for a Ph.D. The courses in Germany are not exactly the same. They are much advanced. I wanted to step up my game raise my bar to get into a good Ph.D. program.

Comment: @scaaahu ... and the research and project work in the university I am accepted to are so amazing and could provide the opportunity for the expertise I need.

Comment: Wait, so you already got accepted to a German university an are now only worrying about visa?

Comment: Yes...I have already been accepted and I am yet to apply for a visa